# How to discover a virus or rootkit on Ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, antivirus, malware

I have been connected to free/public xfinitywifi and my Ubuntu machine has slowed down a lot. I am not sure if it's an update or if I got a virus. Using top and htop, the processes look normal, although there is a looot of affinity for processor #6. Does anyone know of good software to use to diagnose my Ubuntu machine to see if there is something amiss? The machine appears much slower now and that's not fun.

I tried downloading a couple of free antivirus software packages, and I am running into the usual configure + make + make install problems. MIA download links, missing dependencies, and other typical annoying linux bullshit tbh. I am willing to pay for good antivirus software if someone has a good recommendation.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-antivirus.html.en

Answer (score 1):

I'd say finding a **virus** on Linux will be hard (to my knowledge, there are no Linux viruses in the wild). Rootkits are a different thing: booting from a clean medium (e.g. a live CD), and running **[chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/)** would come to mind.

chkrootkit is a well-known rootkit detector (I've used it in the past, many years ago – hadn't a reason to use it afterwards, luckily). Its last version is dated 2/2019, so I'm not sure if it would detect "the latest stuff".

A second well-known tool in this area is **[rkhunter](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/),** which is even available from the Ubuntu repos. I've never tried it, and its latest version is even older than chkrootkit's: 2/2018. And one usually installs it ahead of a potential infection, so I'm not sure if it would be useful in your current situation.